# Comparing typenames in C++

Tags: c++

I typed this into a template function, just to see if it would work:

```
if (T==int)
```

and the intellisense didn't complain. Is this valid C++? What if I did:

```
std::cout << (int)int;  // looks stupid doesn't it.
```

Comment: Intellisense != Compiler

Comment: ... is it valid or not? If so, a little explanation about the inner workings would be great.

Comment: @ Travis G, You should have posted that as an answer... It deserves upvotes really.. :)

Comment: If it doesn't compile, then it is not valid.  And that code won't compile.  As far as the inner workings of Intellisense go, you'd have to ask Microsoft, for a full explanation.  But as to why it doesn't compile...well, it's just not valid because it really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @liaK: Hah...I think James's answer deserves the credit here, since it is informative and stuff.

Comment: If your reason for comparing typenames is to allow special treatment of certain data types, you can simply use template specialization.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just to fit your requirement you should use `typeid` operator. Then your expression would look like

```
if (typeid(T) == typeid(int)) {
    ...
}
```

Obvious sample to illustrate that this really works:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class AClass {
public:
    static bool compare() {
        return (typeid(T) == typeid(int));
    }
};

void main() {
    std::cout << AClass<char>::compare() << std::endl;
    std::cout << AClass<int>::compare() << std::endl;
}
```

So in stdout you'll probably get:

```
0
1
```

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not valid C++.

IntelliSense is not smart enough to find everything that is wrong with code; it would have to fully compile the code to do that, and compiling C++ is very slow (too slow to use for IntelliSense).

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
if(typeid(T) == typeid(int))
```

and this?

```
cout << typeid(int).name();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your probably didn't even instantiate your template, that's why it compiled.

Answer (score 2):

Since C++11, you can use [`std::is_same<T1, T2>::value`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use if (T == int) and std::cout<<(int)int;