# How to compare class types in C++?

Tags: c++, class, types

Lets say I've got:

```
class Base {/*...*/}
class Derived1: public Base {/*...*/}
class Derived2: public Base {/*...*/}
```

..and I've got:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    template<typename DerivedType>
    DerivedType GetDerived();
private:
    vector<Base*> m_classes;
}
```

In the `GetDerived()` function I iterate trough the m_classes vector and I would like to do something like:

```
if(m_classes[i] == DerivedType) {
    return m_classes[i];
}
```

...and lets assume we know that one of the objects in the m_classes will contain a 'DerivedType' object.

**Example:**

```
m_classes[2] = Base* BasePtr = new Derived1;
```

.. in this case I'd like to use the GetDerived function like this:

```
GetDerived<Derived1>();
```

.. and this should return m_classes[2]

How do I do this? How do I compare a base pointer object with a derived class type? More exactly, how should the `GetDerived()` function look like?

Comment: `How do I do this?`  Maybe the question should be "Why do you want to do this?"

Comment: did you try `typeid` operator? 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3930720/365229

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing objects of different classes in the same container when you need to treat them differently is a bad idea.

C++ however has what you're looking for, this time. `dynamic_cast<B>(a)` will try and convert `a` (whatever it is) to type `B`. If the runtime classes do not match, it will return `nullptr`.

Here is how you could write `GetDerived` :

```
template <class Tsearched>
Tsearched *GetDerived() {
    for(auto c : m_classes) {
        if(Tsearched *ptr = dynamic_cast<Tsearched*>(c))
            return ptr;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Or, with the help of a standard algorithm :

```
template <class Tsearched>
Tsearched *GetDerived() {
    auto found = std::find_if(m_classes.begin(), m_classes.end(), [](Base *ptr) {
        return dynamic_cast<Tsearched*>(ptr);
    });
    return found == m_classes.end() ? nullptr : static_cast<Tsearched*>(*found);
}
```

Let me repeat, however, that there is a design issue in here. RTTI (what `dynamic_cast` uses) is neither elegant, nor fast.

Comment: A. Your code can be simplified to a find_if. B. Are you referring to this case or in general about RTTI?

Comment: @black RTTI is typically the last thing to be tried, as cases where it is the best option are exceedingly rare. And even then, it is often but a bandage to work around a design issue. As for the find_if, I'd have to check the iterator before dereferencing it, so there's no size gain, however I will add it for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dynamic_cast<>`:

```
template<typename DerivedType>
std::vector<DerivedType*> GetDerived() { // note: return type changed
 std::vector<DerivedType*> result;
 for (DerivedType* at : this->m_classes) {
  if (DerivedType* as = dynamic_cast<DerivedType*>(at)) {
   result.push_back(as);
  }
 }
 return result;
}
```

`dynamic_cast<>` requires a `Base` type with Run Time Type Information (which will exist on types which have virtual functions).

It's worth mentioning that some people dislike `dynamic_cast<>`, and some conventions/codebases forbid it. It's a tool, and it can be misused.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's not a good idea to do things like that.

You can use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) which returns `nullptr` if the object is not of that type and a pointer to that type otherwise :

```
if (nullptr != dynamic_cast<DerivedType*>(m_classes[i])) 
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

As other people have said, you should see if this is really the best way to attack your problem, but `dynamic_cast` is available in C++. You have to use **Run Time Type Identification** or RTTI.

Once you've turned it on in your compiler options you can do this inside your loop:

```
DerivedType* maybeDerived = dynamic_cast<DerivedType>(m_classes[i]);
if (maybeDerived)
     return maybeDerived;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not valid syntax. You can't have a declaration in the middle of an assignment. However something like http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of can help identify derivations at compile time. As far as identifying derived types at runtime you can use `dynamic_cast` however ideal solutions should not need to do this and it often means there is a potential design flaw in your objects or the way they are being used.

As pointed out by @PaulMcKenzie you should probably be asking yourself "Why?" before worrying about the how.